# Masonry on load height error

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have this problem every time I load this site for the first time the masonry triggers a height problem.

```
<div class="js-masonry" id="masonry" data-masonry-options='{"columnWidth": 390, "itemSelector": ".item","gutter":0 }'>
```

this is my jquery for masonry :

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function()
    {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#masonry').masonry({
                columnWidth: 390,
                itemSelector: '.item',
                gutter: 0
            })
        });
        $('#masonry').masonry({
            columnWidth: 390,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            gutter: 0
        });
    });

</script>
```

this is my site you can try opening it http://enjoykerja.com

Comment: and your problem is? You need to describe it.

Comment: on load website the masonry messed up my web layout

Comment: And what does "messed up" mean. Describe  what happens to your layout  in your question.

Comment: i've added more picture to describe the messed up layout, continue to the botom answer k